# No provider for AngularFire (Angular 2)

Tags: angular, angularfire2

(This is not the same as the existing questions about it)

UPDATE:
I'm using Angular 2 version 2.2.3 and angularfire2 version 2.0.0-beta.6

In the Chrome console I get the error `No provider for AngularFire`. In my main.ts I have this:

```js
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, [
  FIREBASE_PROVIDERS,
  defaultFirebase({
    apiKey: <my-apikey>,
    authDomain: <my-authdomain>,
    databaseURL: <my-databaseurl>,
    storageBucket: <my-storagebucket>
  })
]);
```

In the tutorials I have seen about this they use `bootstrap` instead of `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule`, but in my version of Angular I can't import just `bootstrap`.

Comment: What versions of Angular 2 and AngularFire2 are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your configuration is a little different to that recommended in the [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/1-install-and-setup.md#4-setup-ngmodule).

The AngularFire2-related parts of the `NgModule` configuration in one of my applications look like this:

```js
import {
    AngularFireModule,
    AuthMethods,
    AuthProviders
} from 'angularfire2';

...

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp({
            apiKey: '<some-key>',
            authDomain: '<some-project-authdomain>',
            databaseURL: '<some-database-URL>',
            storageBucket: '<some-storage-bucket>'
        }, {
            method: AuthMethods.Password,
            provider: AuthProviders.Password
        }),
        BrowserModule,
        ...
    ]
})
class AppModule {}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```